# How to create watermark in edit box in MFC VC++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, editbox

I have created an Edit box accepting password but I need to display a watermark or whatever it calls displaying "password" as default just like when we enter our password in windows 8 startup.

thanks

Comment: this might work for you. http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?98691-Adding-placeholders-to-an-edit-box

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761639%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Also related: [EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761653.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very easy thing to do.
Just take an edit control, right click edit control and click "Add Variable".
Give variable name, say "m_myEdit".
Now "OnInitDialog()" you need to write just one line.

```
m_myEdit.SetCueBanner(_T("Password"),TRUE);
```

This will work as you mentioned like windows 8 startup.

Comment: @PallaviRai you are welcome :) If my answer is helpful, you can accept it as answer. Which will helpful for future users.

Comment: It's generally more valuable to provide full code in an answer. Instead of describing which steps are required for a particular version of a particular IDE, reproduce the [DDX_Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z04ab59a.aspx) entries required in `DoDataExchange`. Alternatively, a call to [CWnd::GetDlgItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d16yhw.aspx) will suffice.

Comment: I provided the steps so that even beginner can understand. and its only one line code that i have provided. I'm feeling its more flexible to work with variable instead of ID's.